# How to pass an UnsafePointer<UInt8> to a C API by reference?

Tags: swift, openssl, pass-by-reference, swift3, unsafe-pointers

I wrote some Swift 2.2 code to interact with `OpenSSL` C APIs and now I'm trying to convert it to Swift 3.

In Swift 2

```
let octets = pkcs7_d_data(pkcs7_d_sign(receiptPKCS7).memory.contents)
var ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(octets.memory.data)

// now pass pointer by reference
ASN1_get_object(&ptr, &length, &type, &xclass, end - ptr)
```

In Swift 3, I've had to make a couple changes

```
// use guard so i dont have to constantly unwrap these values

guard let octets = pkcs7_d_data(pkcs7_d_sign(receiptPKCS7).pointee.contents),
      var ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(octets.pointee.data) else {
    return nil
}

ASN1_get_object(&ptr, &length, &type, &xclass, end - ptr)
//              ^^^ this is now a compiler error
```

Unfortunately, I can no longer pass `ptr` to `ASN1_get_object` by reference, due to this error:

```
Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: Implicit conversion from UnsafePointer<UInt8> to UnsafePointer<UInt8>? requires a temporary
```

and then the rest of the error is cut off (there's no expand arrow).

What I've tried:

- changing the `ptr` assignment to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>(octets.pointee.data)?` but then I'm told that my existing assignment **already** produces an optional
- changed the `UnsafePointer` to `UnsafeMutablePointer`

What needs to change here?

Comment: I haven't used Swift 3 yet, but I was dealing with similar in 2.3 the other day. Does directly doing `ASN1_get_object(&octet.pointee.data...)` not do what you need?

Comment: First, it still throws an error about not passing an immutable as inout, and second I'd like to keep a separate reference as I move the `ptr` around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `octets.pointee.data` is a 
`UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>!`, but `ASN1_get_object` expects
the address of a `UnsafePointer<UInt8>?`.

The following code compiles, but I could not test it:

```
if
    let octets = pkcs7_d_data(pkcs7_d_sign(receiptPKCS7).pointee.contents),
    let data = octets.pointee.data {

    var ptr: UnsafePointer? = UnsafePointer(data) // (*)
    var length = 0
    var tag: Int32 = 0
    var xclass: Int32 = 0

    ASN1_get_object(&ptr, &length, &tag, &xclass, Int(octets.pointee.length))
}
```

`(*)` is the pointer conversion which makes it compile.

Comment: This appears to work, but am I not losing anything by not specifying `UInt8`? Also I can't assign `ptr` like this when it's in a `guard` condition so it seems I now have to unwrap it each time I use it.

Comment: @ray: `ptr` has the type `UnsafePointer<UInt8>?`, you can verify that with option-click on the variable in Xcode. The `UInt8` is inferred automatically, you could more verbosely write `var ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>? = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data)`. – Can't you define `ptr` *after* the guard statement?

Comment: I can, I'm just sad about the fact that I can't seem to assign pointer **and** specify that it's optional if it's part of a conditional. Once I define it outside `guard`, I have to unwrap `ptr` every time I use it.